# Zend AjaxContext, _redirect and hash navigation

Tags: zend-framework, redirect, ajaxcontext

first post in SO, even though I've been browsing it for years now to solve those mind-blowing and not so much coding problems.

What I want to do is:
* Use hash navigation (#!/).
* Use Zend controller actions, not php files.
* Load these actions through javascript/jQuery.

So far, I've got this working:
indexController, several Actions, each attached to AjaxContext via addActionContext(), I can call them though my javascript/jQuery file via "hashchange" plugin jQuery(window).hashchange(function(){ bla bla }). I can cycle through actions just fine.

But I want to redirect the user to a login page if he/she is not logged in, which brings me to my issue: How can I achieve that? The redirection is made to another controller (login controller, login action). I was trying something like $this->_redirect('/#!/login/login'); w/o any luck (yes, I've set up an AjaxContext in that controller's init). I keep getting a redirection error ("The page isn't redirecting properly"). If I just type in the address bar "/#!/login/login" I get everything display properly.

Anyway, thanks in advance!
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Now this starts to get complicated if you ever introduce other non-ajax contexts, but you could add the Ajax context to the Error Controller. Then have the error controller return JSON for the unauthenticated exception if the active context was AJAX (and keep the redirect if the default context was active). Your JS would then listen for that specific error provided by the JSON and manually bounce the user to the appropriate login URL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Bishop, I get your idea. The thing is, I cannot even get to the ErrorController, the redirection error is generated by the browser, not the application. Maybe I misinterpreted your approach, any further explanation will be appreciated :)